# React-day-picker test with enzyme & jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-day-picker

I was trying to test `react-day-picker` from https://react-day-picker.js.org/examples/selected-multiple with `enzyme` and also `jest` but unfortunately I am getting an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of undefined`. Mostly I want to test `handleDayClick()` method

my component

```
export default class MultiDayPicker extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedDays: []
  };

  handleDayClick = (day, {selected}) => {
    const {selectedDays} = this.state;

    if (selected) {
      const selectedIndex = selectedDays.findIndex(selectedDay =>
        DateUtils.isSameDay(selectedDay, day)
      );

      selectedDays.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
    } else {
      selectedDays.push(day);
    }

    this.setState({selectedDays});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <DayPicker
        selectedDays={this.state.selectedDays}
        onDayClick={this.handleDayClick}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

my tests:

```
it('should call the `handleDayClick` function', () => {
    const component = shallow(<MultiDayPicker {...defaultProps} />);

    expect(component.instance().handleDayClick()).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I will appreciate any ideas or help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must add modifiers prop on DayPicker

```html
<DayPicker
    selectedDays={this.state.selectedDays}
    onDayClick={this.handleDayClick}
    modifier={{selected: this.state.selectedDays}}
 />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).